# How to fill List of object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

I Have an object "Kit" on my code.

```
class Kit
{
    private int _CK_ID;

    public int CK_ID
    {
        get { return _CK_ID; }
        set { _CK_ID = value; }
    }

}
```

in my code i want to fill a list of Kit

```
List<Kit> kits = new List<Kit>();
```

now i want to fill the kits with data from the db

i have one solution:

bring the data to a reader and then loop and insert new kit into the list.

but i want to do it "nice" how can i do something like this

```
kits.fillData();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an extension method for `List<Kit>` like this:

```
public static void fillData(this List<Kit> kits) { }
```

and then inside there fill the `kits` object. Now, you'll need to put that into a `static` class and you'll need to include the namespace at the top of the file you want to use it at. So, if you had code like this:

```
namespace MyApplication.Extensions
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static void fillData(this List<Kit> kits) { }
    }
}
```

and then in the file you want to use it in add a `using` statement:

```
using MyApplication.Extensions;
```

so when you have a `List<Kit>` you can do this:

```
List<Kit> kits = new List<Kit>();
kits.fillData();
```

Comment: I think the OP wants a way of actually filling the data?

Comment: @LukeHennerley, **please note the actual question.** `but i want to do it "nice" how can i do something like this`

Comment: **please note the bit before** `I have one solution to do this` **BUT** `I want a "nice" how can I do something like this`

Comment: it's "nice" - i get an error Error 1 Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<IDD.ClutchKits.ClutchKit>' is less accessible than method 'IDD.ClutchKits.MyExtensions.fillData(System.Collections.Generic.List<IDD.ClutchKits.ClutchKit>)'

Comment: @eyalb, that's because your class is currently ***`private`***, make the class ***`public`***.

Comment: the class and the method is public

Comment: @eyalb, if the class is defined like it is in your question, it's private.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you want to structure your code and what you are most familiar with you could use something like [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/ef.aspx) or [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/).

This is obviously dependant on your framework, task requirements and skill sets.

If this isn't an option you could do this, based on your `stored procedure` or select statement bringing out the same column names as the `Kit` class.

```
public class KitList : List<Kit>
{
  public void FillList()
  {
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(""))
    {
      var cmd = new SqlCommand("GetData", con);
      var dt = new DataTable();
      var sda = new SqlDataAdapater(cmd);
      sda.Fill(dt);
      foreach(var row in dt.Rows)
      {
        Kit k = new Kit();
        foreach(var col in dt.Columns)
        {
          k.GetType().GetProperty(col.Name).SetValue(obj, row[col.Name], null);
        }
        this.Add(k);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: there is a variable obj in .SetValue(obj, row[col.Name],null); where does obj come from ?

Comment: @joedotnot `obj` is `k` in this instance, typo sorry

Answer (score 1):

Why would the `Kit` object fill itself ?

You can implement something like :

```
class KitCollection : List<Kit>
{
    public void FillData()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int i = 10; //let say 10 random data

        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            Kit kit = new Kit();
            kit.CK_ID = rnd.Next(1, 100);
            this.Add(kit);
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like :

```
    KitCollection list = new KitCollection(); // can be easily cast to List<Kit>
    list.FillData();
```

`Random Data` ? Surely, In that case you can certainly fill it, using a simple method like

```
private static void FillRandomData(List<Kit> lst)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int i = 10; //let say 10 random data

    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        Kit kit = new Kit();
        kit.CK_ID = rnd.Next(1, 100);
        lst.Add(kit);
    }
}
```

Comment: no, the kit can fill itself because it's a row from the table